# Need help setting up a Flash development environment

Tags: android, actionscript-3, flash, apache-flex

I'm fresh-out-of-the-water new with Adobe Flash, and I'm trying to start programming games with free software.

I know I need an IDE and a SDK. I've found [FlashDevelop](http://flashdevelop.org/), but I'm confused about choosing an SDK. I believe I'm supposed to get Flex SDK, but I would think that's for using Flex code; I want to use ActionScript. Is the Flex SDK used for ActionScript?

What other software do I need? For example, how would I make sprites and animations?

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a tool, library or favorite off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam.

Comment: @MikeW: I've reworked the question so that it can be answered objectively

Comment: @WarrenYoung The question is still off-topic for the reason I gave. The wording is taken directly from [so] wording. The whole question would fit better now on [softwarerecs.se]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I believe I'm supposed to get Flex SDK, but I would think that's for using Flex code; I want to use ActionScript

Flex is an application development framework built on top of Flash, written in ActionScript, so it necessarily includes an [AS3](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ActionScript) compiler.

(It happens to be the same compiler that turns [Flex MXML files](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MXML) into [SWF files](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Swf), but that's just an implementation detail.)

For all practical purposes, there are no other free AS3 compilers. During the many years while Flash was purely a closed system, there were a few attempts to create open tooling for Flash, but when [Adobe open-sourced Flex years ago](https://flex.apache.org/about-history.html), they effectively killed off all of those third-party projects. Now everyone uses the Flex SDK, even those not building on top of the Flex framework.

You shouldn't need to download the Flex SDK separately. [The FlashDevelop installer will do that for you.](http://www.flashdevelop.org/wikidocs/index.php?title=Installation)

> how would I make sprites and animations?

If you were expecting to be able to draw the sprites and graphically set up animations with keyframes and such, the only sensible way to do it is to use [Flash Professional](https://www.adobe.com/products/flash.html).

By restricting yourself to pure AS3 and free tools, you're limiting yourself to doing everything programmatically. It may be possible to convert drawings in other formats to AS3 code, but that's really going about it the hard way. When you read that Mr. Studly Game Designer, Jr. wrote his game in AS3, he almost certainly didn't draw all of the graphic assets in AS3 code. Instead, he probably created the game in Flash Professional, using its drawing tools for the sprites and possibly some of the animations, and wrote AS3 code behind all of that for the game logic.

For a new game, you should be writing it in HTML5 instead. The free tooling is much more mature for this, since the web has been an open platform its whole life, rather than just for the past three years, as with the Flex SDK.

If you have existing tutorials and such on AS3 game development, I recommend that you use [CreateJS](http://createjs.com/), which wraps the native HTML5 canvas and such with an API that mimics the Flash SDK. ActionScript is derived from JavaScript, so a lot of AS3 code ports straight over to JavaScript + CreateJS.

The major things that don't port straight across are all AS3 extensions to JS, such as the C++-like object system and static typing. If you absolutely have to have those features, there are [a bunch of languages out there that compile down to JavaScript](http://www.drdobbs.com/jvm/the-javascript-alternatives/240166433) to give JS a different flavor.

The reason I recommend writing new software in HTML5 today is that [Flash is in decline](http://w3techs.com/technologies/details/cp-flash/all/all), [particularly on mobile devices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adobe_Flash#Decline_on_mobile_devices). This is objective fact, not just my opinion; even Adobe is saying this now.

(I assume the mobile question is important for you, since you've tagged your question `android`. [Flash is no longer available for Android](https://forums.adobe.com/message/4675670), officially.)

And that brings me back to Flash Professional: recent versions of Flash now optionally generate CreateJS based HTML5 output, straight from the tool. I found the resulting code to be reasonably clear, such that once I had gotten my graphical assets drawn the way I liked, I could then stop using Flash Professional, and work on the underlying logic in my standard programmer's text editor. Flash is great as a drawing and animation tool, but it's awfully poor as a poor programmer's IDE.

Another of the advantages of the HTML5 stack is that you can draw your "sprites" in any [SVG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Svg)-aware vector drawing tool (e.g. [Inkscape](http://inkscape.org/en/)) or as alpha-blended PNGs and use them in your game directly. You can write CreateJS based code by hand. Flash Professional would make some of this easier, but it's entirely optional with the HTML5 stack.

Comment: Thank-you for the detailed response!  I guess I will try the free trial and if I don't like it enough for that much money I will look in to HTML5.  Thanks again.

Comment: @user3638817: I wasn't exactly recommending Flash Professional. There's a pretty good chance it will follow Flash Builder and Fireworks into the dustbin of history. I think starting with HTML5 and JavaScript better matches your goal of developing purely with free software. It's where the market has been headed for years, and there's no indication that it's going to be superseded any time soon.